# unable to connect to sql server analysis services on windows vista

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I just installed sql server 2008 developer edition on my windows vista machine. The installation was successful. Reporting service is working fine. But I am not getting any option to connect to "Analysis Services" in sql management studio.

The only options i get for "Server Type" while connecting are -

```
1. Database Engine
2. Sql Server Compact
```

Pls. suggest. Thanks.

Comment: better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Thanks for the suggestion. Just asked on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided at below url:

https://serverfault.com/questions/152904/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-analysis-services-on-windows-vista